# MSSQL users for database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlcmd

I have a SQL server 2008 and need to create a user for the database.

I did

```
CREATE LOGIN myuser with PASSWORD='pass'
CREATE USER myuser FOR LOGIN myuser
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'my_db'
```

After I've done with these commands, I executed

```
select suser_sname(owner_sid) from sys.databases where name = 'my_db'
```

the result:

---

sa

How can I add another user to the db = my_db and set all PRIVILEGES to this user?

Comment: The owner of the database is unrelated to the user you just created (and it's fine for the database owner to be `sa`). Adding a user to the `db_owner` role gives them functionally the same privileges as the owner (within the database), so you should be done. (Assuming the `my_db` in `sp_addrolemember` is a typo and you really meant `myuser`, otherwise this command can't work.) You *can* change the database owner (`ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::...`) but that's almost certainly unnecessary/not what you want.

Comment: As a FYI, SQL Server 2008's (extended) support ends in 19 days; you really need to look into upgrade paths as soon as you can.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, so, how can I make sure, that myuser is admin of my_db?

Comment: @JeroenMostert because now, when I'm going inside the database and tried to find who has admin privileges on the db my_db, I can't see anybody

Comment: From 2012 onwards there's `IS_ROLEMEMBER`. In 2008 you'll have to manually join up `sys.database_role_members` and `sys.database_principals`. That will still only tell you who's part of the `db_owner` group -- sysadmins have admin privileges on the DB without needing to be a member of any database role, of course.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, so how I use myuser as an admin for my_db? Could you please help me?

Comment: I don't see what your problem is. Are you saying `USE my_db; EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'myuser'` doesn't give `myuser` the privileges to do what they need in `my_db`? How are you testing that and what do you really need to be able to do?

Comment: @JeroenMostert how can I check permissions for the myuser? Do you have some commands?

Comment: `SELECT mp.name FROM sys.database_role_members rm JOIN sys.database_principals rp ON rm.role_principal_id = rp.principal_id JOIN sys.database_principals mp ON rm.member_principal_id = mp.principal_id WHERE rp.[name] = 'db_owner'` will give you the list of members of the `db_owner` role. But you're obviously better off testing permissions by having the user test that they can do whatever it is they need to be able to do -- the proof of the pudding is in the eating.